# Create a pattern to find out if the string contains a divide by zero operation

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a pattern to find out whether there is a divide by zero operation going on in a string.
Following are some example strings:

1. `<<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>   /  1 * <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>> / 00  + <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Gender>> / 001`
2. `<<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>/0`
3. `1    /    0000 + 1       /   00`
4. `1/0`

There can be multiple spaces anywhere in the string, operators(+,-,/,*,**,AND,OR,<,>,<=,>=) can be used anywhere in the string. If any double quote(") or single quote(') encounters in a string, it should return false.
Can someone help me with this?

I tried pattern ".+/*0+[^0-9]*" but it doesn't work for all cases.

A pattern which should not be considered a divide zero pattern.
Ex : LENGTH("/0")

Comment: Are only the last 2 items valid? `\b\d+\s*\/\s*0+\b` https://regex101.com/r/tEBepz/1 If there also can not be quotes in the string `^(?![^"'\n]*["']).*\b\d+\s*\/\s*0+\b` https://regex101.com/r/GEfROq/1

Comment: all 4 are valid, if a divide by zero operation is found, then it should return true and there can be many such combinations.

Comment: java, sorry i tagged javascript also by mistake

Comment: It looks like also strings with `<<...>>` perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/HxuBqI/1

Comment: Try `text.matches("([^'\"]*['\"]|.*/\\s*0+(?:\\.0*)?\\b).*")` - if there is a match, fail the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried this, other cases work, but it fails in one case KLENGTH("/0")
It considers this operation also as divide by zero, which is actually not a divide by zero operation.

Comment: @aby007 It does not match `LENGTH("/0")` See https://regex101.com/r/UUXULn/1 Are there other scenario's that should/should not match. Are the parts `<<...>>` relevant? If not, can you update the examples in the question?

Comment: yes those parts are also relevant, updated the string which should not match

Answer (score 0):

If there should not be quotes in the string, you can start the pattern with an assertion that there are no quotes present in the string.

```
^(?![^"'\n]*["']).*?(?:\b\d+\b|<<.*?>>)\s*\/\s*0+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![^"'\n]*["'])` Negative lookahead, assert not `"` or `'` in the string
- `.*?` Match any char as few as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\b\d+\b` Match 1+ digits between word boundaries
  - `|` Or
  - `<<.*?>>` match `<<...>>`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\s*\/\s*` Match `/` between optional whitespace chars
- `0+\b` Match 1+ zeroes and a word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCYUcO/1).

Code example

```
String regex = "^(?![^\"'\\n]*[\"']).*?(?:\\b\\d+|<<.*?>>)\\s*\\/\\s*0+\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

String[] strings = { 
        "1) <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>   /  1 * <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>> / 00  + <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Gender>> / 001",
        "2) <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>/0",
        "3) 1    /    0000 + 1       /   00",
        "4) 1/0",
        "5) 1/0\"",
        "6) 1    /    0900 + 1       /   99"
};
for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match for: " + s);   
    }            
}
```

Output

```
Match for: 1) <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>   /  1 * <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>> / 00  + <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Gender>> / 001
Match for: 2) <<Employee Profile/Employee Data/Employee/Age>>/0
Match for: 3) 1    /    0000 + 1       /   00
Match for: 4) 1/
```

Comment: @aby007 Try the one without the doubled backslashes `^(?![^"'\n]*["']).*?(?:\b\d+\b|<<.*?>>)\s*\/\s*0+\b`